# Twilio import error in python shell

Tags: macos, python-2.7, import, twilio

Installed Twilio successfully however when I attempt to import it in either the shell or terminal I get this error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
 import twilio
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
   from .rest.exceptions import TwilioRestException
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
   from .base import set_twilio_proxy
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/base.py", line 6, in <module>
   from twilio.rest.resources import Connection
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
   from .util import (
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/util.py", line 5, in <module>
  import pytz
 ImportError: No module named pytz
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here? My version of Python is 2.7.9 and my pip installer is current as well. Output Error above is from importing in IDLE shell.

Comment: It looks as though you don't have a module named pytz.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio library requires [pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) to be installed. Easiest way to get it installed is by running this on your terminal:

`pip install pytz`

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah I finally figured it out. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Glad it works. Wanna mark it as answered for future reference then?